# Proper way to construct Option object: Option(value) vs Some(value)

Tags: scala, scala-option

What is the pros and cons of 2 ways of initiating `Option` objects:

1.

```
def getAmount: Option[Int] = {
  val a: Int = 1
  Option(a)
}
```

2.

```
def getAmount: Option[Int] = {
  val a: Int = 1
  Some(a)
}
```

Which should I use?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two important differences. First, `Option` will return a `None` if its argument is null:

```
scala> val x: Option[String] = Some(null)
x: Option[String] = Some(null)

scala> val y: Option[String] = Option(null)
y: Option[String] = None
```

This can be useful, but it's not always what you want, and (just as importantly) it suggests that there's a reasonable chance that the argument may be null in some cases, which can be misleading.

`Some` is more appropriate for cases where you want to produce an `Option` around a value that you know isn't null. Unfortunately the second difference is that the return type of `Some(foo)` is `Some[Whatever]`, not `Option[Whatever]`, which can be really inconvenient in some situations where having `Some` inferred means you'll get type errors when you try to use `None` or `Option` in certain positions later. In these cases you have to use `Some(foo): Option[Whatever]`, which is pretty unpleasant.

For example, suppose we've got a list of strings representing (we hope) integers, and we want to parse and sum them. We want a `None` if there's a parsing error and a `Some(total)` otherwise. The following is a fairly reasonable way to do this in a single traversal using the standard library:

```
List("1", "2", "3").foldLeft(Some(0)) {
  case (acc, item) => for {
    t <- acc
    n <- util.Try(item.toInt).toOption
  } yield t + n
}
```

Except that this doesn't work—we get a type error:

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int]
 required: Some[Int]
                  t <- acc
                    ^
```

We can fix this by writing `.foldLeft(Some(0): Option[Int])`, but ugh.

This isn't an issue in your specific example because the return type is explicitly `Option[Int]`, so you don't need to worry about type inference. In that case `Some(a)` is the right choice.

As a side note, [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) provides `some` and `none` constructors that help you avoid the type inference problem and noisy solutions like `Some(foo): Option[Whatever]`:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> some(10)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(10)

scala> none[Int]
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

Both return types are `Option`, which makes type inference a lot easier. You can trivially define these yourself if you don't want to use Scalaz:

```
scala> def some[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)
some: [A](a: A)Option[A]

scala> def none[A]: Option[A] = None
none: [A]=> Option[A]
```

If you use these instead of `Some` and `None` you never have to worry about an inappropriately specific type being inferred.

To summarize: use `Option(foo)` only in situations where the argument may be null (which ideally should only be for things like interoperability with Java). Use `Some(foo)` in cases where the value has been explicitly typed as `Option`. If the inferred type will be `Some[Whatever]`, add a `: Option[Whatever]` type annotation, or use something like Scalaz's `some`.

Answer (score 0):

As for me it's just a question of common sense. Of course you can imagine the case where you expect something exactly of the type Some and None is not allowed. But usually the second way looks much more natural: return type is Option and actual implementation is either Some(x) or None. Technically, from [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3d76836bc81c3ec183e83ee186e447ff212507d0/src/library/scala/Option.scala), Option(x) calls `apply()` method of a companion object:

```
object Option {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList
  def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
  def empty[A] : Option[A] = None
}
```

And Some(a) calls `apply()` method on case class..

```
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def get = x
}
```

All other methods are the same. The use case with `null` objects is explained pretty well in the [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) answer.

Comment: There are differences in their behavior—just try `Some[String](null)` and `Option[String](null)`.

Comment: You are completely right about their initialization and you explained this user case quite clear in your answer! I will edit my answer to be accurate.